# Failed to create field. Please try again later: Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to count the occurrence of an event on Google Data Studio (via a BigQuery Connector), however, even for a correct formula "*Please try again later appears*". The error sometimes to invalid formula.

I have tried refreshing the data source and yet there is no luck.

Here is the query:

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN event_name = 'Cashin' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to create the same metric, and I managed to do it. I think this is some kind of temporary data studio error in your area. I advise you to try later.
[image]